# Умеет ли Yandex-Tank работать с HTTPS?

Tags: яндекс-танк, нагрузочное-тестирование

Я тестирую API, которое работает через HTTPS, и мне интересно, можно ли заставить *Яндекс.Танк* использовать именно этот протокол.

Answer (score 5):

Да, нужно указать в конфигурационном файле танка в секции

```
[phantom]
ssl=1
```

Если нужен TLS с аутентификацией клиента, то в [документации модуля phantom](https://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html?#options) есть описание нужных опций.

Comment: В yaml-варианте это выглядит как `phantom: {ssl: true}`, и ещё нужно не забыть указать 443 порт.